# How to assign multiple values to multiple keys with a single command

Tags: python, dictionary, assign, multiple-value

I have dictionary like:

```
Info = {
  "City_Name" : {
    "Population" : None,
    "Population_Density" : None
    }
}
```

I want to assign values to "Population" and "Population_Density" keys. I actually can do that with the use of the following commands:

```
Info["City_Name"]["Population"] = 20000 
Info["City_Name"]["Population_Density"] = 200
```

But instead, I want to do that with a single command like:

```
Info["City_Name"]["Population","Population_Density"] = 20000 , 200
```

But this doesn't work, the command above generates a new key... 
(In fact, a function returns me those values, and therefore, I need to do that with a single command)

## Edit:

I needed to mention; without using:

```
Info["City_Name"]["Population"],Info["City_Name"]["Population_Density"] = 20000, 200
```

The key-names of my dictionary are so long that, it is hard to follow; they take a lot of space. I also need to assig three values to three keys. Therefore, I was wondering if there is any way to do that with just a single modification on the part, that is different than each other (eg; "Population" and "Population_Density").

Comment: Try `Info["City_Name"]["Population"],Info["City_Name"]["Population_Density"]=20000,200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Info["City_Name"].update({"Population": 20000, "Population_Density": 200})
```

Comment: I get the numerical values from a function, and therefore, I cannot assign the values to key-names like the way you proposed. (For such a use; , I have to assign the values that my function returns to an intermediate variable. And then, I have to assign them the way you proposed. However, it is not the way I want to do it... But, anyway, thanks a lot for your response!)

Comment: So does your function return a list of values e.g. `[20000, 200]`?

Comment: No, it actually returns arrays; my function is like: `def myfunction(): ... return array1, array2, array3`
So, I have an array instead of 20000 and another array of values instead of 200... 
But leaving the array structure aside, I even do not know how to implement it even if my function would have returned numerical values.

Comment: What about `Info["City_Name"].update(dict(zip(["Population", "Population_Density"], myfunction())))`?

Comment: That's it! I have combined your solution with @mhlester 's solution; so; `d= Info["City_Name"]` and then: `d.update(dict(zip(["Population", "Population_Density"], myfunction())))` . Now, it is exactly as I like to have. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Only way to do *exactly* what you're asking is:

```
Info["City_Name"]["Population"], Info["City_Name"]["Population_Density"] = 20000, 200
```

Otherwise it takes `Info["City_Name"]`, and creates a new key `("Population", "Population_Density")` (a tuple), and assigns another tuple, `(20000, 200)` to that

Or you can do it in two lines:

```
d = Info["City_Name"]
d["Population"], d["Population_Density"] = 20000, 200
```

Comment: That's true, thanks a lot. But, the key-names of my dictionary are so long that, it is hard to follow; it takes a lot of space. (I am actually assigning three values to three keys). Therefore, I was wondering if there is any way to just to modify the part, which is different than each other. In our case; "Population" and "Population_Density".

Comment: I tried different combinations of parentheses, curly braces etc. but, it didn't help...

Comment: Not without storing an intermediate variable for `Info["City_Name"]` and then using that on a subsequent line

Comment: If I will not receive any solution, I can do your suggestion. I tried to implement it but I couldn't. How can I do that; how can we store an intermediate variable for such a string?